# How do you know when to substitute and how to avoid trivial situations such as x=x when solving systems of equations?

Tags: linear-algebra

I came across this question:

Find the equation of a parabola given the intercepts. X intercepts = (4,0) and (-2,0). Y intercept = (0,6)

I used the following method to solve this problem:

we have the following system:

a*(0-h)^2 + k = 6 [1]

a*(4-h)^2 + k = 0 [2]

a*(-2-h)^2 + k = 0 [3]

subbing in the y intercept:

a*(x-h)^2 + k = 6

k = 6-h^2*a

subbing in k for the x intercept (4,0):

a*(4-h)^2+6-h^2*a = 0

a = 3/(4*(h-2))

Now, I used this new information and subbed it back into the equation for the y intercept thinking that by introducing this new information, I would find the value for h:

a*(0-h)^2+k = 6

3/(4*(h-2))*(0-h)^2+(6-h^2)*(3/(4*(h-2))) = 6

h = h

Then I had no choice, but to substitute the newly found information for the variable 'k' and 'a' into the [3] equation to find the answer. I know how to find the answer, but I do not know when to substitute to avoid arriving at trivial situations like h=h. So, how do you know when to substitute a piece of information into an equation in a system of linear equations to avoid such trivial situations?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Hint: don't use the vertex form, instead use the standard form as it gives two equations in two unknowns, as opposed to three equations in two unknowns.

Answer (score 0):

- You have 3 unknowns and 3 equations right the unknowns being a, h, k.
  You need to use information from all equations to solve the system.
- You took information from equation 1 put it in equation 2 and were
  expecting to somehow solve the variables, but clearly that wont work.
  If you had possibly got value of h right in equation in 1 and 2 you
  would have got the value of a and k also. which is obviously not
  going to happen. Hence one must involve the third equation.
- Another way to look at it is, you wrote a in terms of h, k in terms
  of a ( which can be written in terms of h) from the first 2 equations themselves. You would now need
  another unique relation between h, k, a to replace and find the final
  answer. which is equation 3.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Could you please elaborate on why another unique relation between 'h', 'k' and 'a' is required to find the answer? Because the understanding that I held while solving this question was that ensuring an equation contains only one variable would be enough to find its value. That's why I subbed in my equation for 'a' in terms of h into the equation for 'k' given in terms of 'h' and 'a' and then I subbed in both equations into equation 1 so that the equation only had the one variable, 'h.' I thought that it would help me find the value for 'h', but obviously it didn't.

Comment: As in, we cannot just say that if i have an equation in one variable it guarantees an answer, The 2 relations you got were actually.  restatements of the 1st and 2nd equations. To use this relations we need a third equation(relation) which is equation 3

Comment: Alright, I understand what you mean now. Thank you for helping me improve my knowledge.